# Jquery Image Slider works in Dreamweaver but not in Google Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dreamweaver

I've been struggling for the past couple of days to fix this Jquery slider and I dont know whats going on. When I set it 'Live' in HTML Dreamweaver, it works. One problem is that, it wont center to the middle of the screen, and the images slide from top-down instead of right-left. It also shows the next upcoming image under the slider before being put on the side (like a 'glitch')  and I dont understand why it is doing this. When previewing it into Google Chrome, the slider didnt come up, it just came up with still images of the photos that were suppose to be in the slider. Can someone please help me out? How do I fix this issue :( its really been stressing me out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="blueberry.css" />
<style type="text/css">
*{
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #F0F0F0;
    font: 14px/20px Arial, San-Serif;
    color: #555;    
    margin: 0;
}
h1 { 
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 180%;
    line-height: 120%;
    padding: 5% 0:
}
h2 {
    text-decoration: underline;
    line-height: 280%;
    padding-left: 2%;   
}
h3  {
    line-height: 110%;
    padding: 5% 0;
}
p {
    padding: 1%;    
}
a {
    color: #FFF;    
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: underline; 
}
header {
    background: #405580;
    width: 100%;
    height: 86px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.90;  
}
#logo {
    maergin: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    height: 79px;
    background: url(http://images.cooltext.com/4390568.png) no-repeat center;
}
nav {
    float: right;
    padding: 35px 20px 20px 0;
}
#menu-icon {
    display:hidden;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/icon.png) center;
}
a:hover#menu-icon {
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
ul {
    list-style: none    
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    floating: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
.current {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#doc {
    margin: 40px 0;
}
#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1140;
    margin-top: 110px;
}
.blueberry {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin-top: 110px;  
}
section {
    width: 29%;
    float: left;
    margin: 2% 2%;
    text-align: center; 
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
article {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 4%;
}
aside {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 35%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 3%;
}
ul. gym li {
    padding-left: 3%
}
footer {
    background: #333333;
    width: 100%;    
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.90%;
}
footer p, footer h3 {
    color: #FFF;
}
footer p a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.social li {
    display: inline;
}
ul.social li img {
    height: 50px;
}
footer.second {
    border-top: 1px solid #4D4E50;
    background-color: #333333;
    max-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.95;
} 
/*------------------MEDIA!!----------*/
@media screen and (max-width: 478px) {
    body { 
        position: absolute;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 740px) {
    header {
        position: absolute 
    }
    #menu-icon {
        display: inline-block
    }nav ul, nav: active ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 20px;
        background: #405580;
        border: 1px solid #FFF;
        right: 20px;
        top: 60px;
        width: 50%;
        border-radius: 2px 0 2px 2px;
    }
    nav li {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    nav:hover ul {
        display: block;
    }
    section { 
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    article { 
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    aside { 
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
}

}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src= "jquery.blueberry.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.blueberry').blueberry();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#" id="logo"></a>
        <nav>
            <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class= "current">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Orders</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav><br />
</header>
    <div id="doc">
        <div id="content"> 
            <div class="blueberry">
                <ul class="slides" >
                    <li><img src="http://skelbiu-img.dgn.lt/1_5_206818520/surenkame-knygas.jpg" alt="BookOpening" width="960" height="476" /> </li>
                    <li><img src="http://www.abc.net.au/news/image/5668412-3x2-940x627.jpg " alt="BookSection" width="960" height="476" /> </li>
                  <li><img src="http://s3-ec.buzzfed.com/static/2014-10/22/15/enhanced/webdr10/edit-wide-942-1414005865-6.jpg" alt="BookLane" width="960" height="476" /> </li>
                  <li><img src="http://pfauth.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/03_Shakespeare_and_Company-975x327.jpg" alt="BookRange" width="960" height="476" /> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <section>            
     <img src="http://www.sunlitemitre10.com.au/site/assets/media/tick.png" alt="Tick" width="70" height="70" />
       <h1> WELCOME! </h1>
        <p> Hello! Welcome to our website. If you are a local... see you in real time and space on your next visit ... for cheap secondhand books. If you're from somewhere else, come talk to us on the World Wide Web, and if you're visiting Geelong anytime soon, we hope you'll come by.</p>
</section>
<section>
     <img src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/Bcg/Krr/BcgKrr9zi.png" alt="Tick" width="70" height="70"  />
       <h1> GOOD NEWS </h1>
        <p> All books are going to be 5% off in July and December, 2015! We'll be selling a range of secondhand books, and selected new ones.</p>
</section>
<section>
       <img src="http://www.sunlitemitre10.com.au/site/assets/media/tick.png" alt="Tick" width="70" height="70" />
        <h1> HISTORY </h1>
        <p> In August 2001, Mary and John have opened this used book shop located in: 123 Moorabool Street, in Geelong. 
Since 2015, we have  started opening at 9 a.m.!  We must be the only book shop in Geelong that open up at this hour, and it's  been said to be the best Secondhand Bookshop in Geelong.</p>
    </section>
  <div class="clear"></div>  
     <section>
        <h1> Do you have books to sell? </h1>
        <img src= "http://mycollegeguide.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/selling_books_2.jpg" alt="sell" width="400" height="350" /> 
        <p> We are always on the look out for secondhand books. Do try us if you have any that you no longer require, we may well be interested, for cash or exchange. PLEASE PHONE FIRST, to arrange a convenient time. </p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2> IMPORTANT NOTICE! </h2>
       <img src="http://storage.googleapis.com/wzukusers/user-14023369/images/559eb2ee1fbecjiSir57/Fanned-Book1cropped_400.jpg" alt="imp" width="400" height="353" />
<p> From Monday October 5th to Friday October 10th, we will be closing early, for stocktake. The shop will be open until 1pm. Saturday, on the  11th we will return to normal trading hours. Apologies for any inconvenience.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h1> Take a read </h1>
        <img src="https://writesandwrongsblog.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/elylanguages_1892125c.jpg" alt="sit" width="460" height="288" />
        <p> Come and stop by the reading area and see if we've got the book that you're looking for in stock. We also got stock cards, wrapping paper and various journals and more. </p>
        </section>
     <footer>
        <section>
            <h3><b> Best Second-hand Bookshop in Geelong </b></h3>
            <p> <b> - Mary & John </b><br><br>
             </p>
        </section>

        <section>
            <h3> Connect with Us! </h3>
            <ul class="social" >
                <li> <a href="#"><img src= "http://lifeallieslab.com/images/fb-icon.png" alt="fb" height="59" width="55"/></a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"><img src= "http://pictures.dealer.com/d/dickdyervolvovcna/0008/0304ac7e766dd3685950e8f2fba330a0x.jpg" alt="g" height="36" width="36"/></a></li> 
                <li> <a href="#"><img src= "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/twitter_circle_color-512.png" alt="twitter" height="40" width="40"/></a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"><img src= "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/256/pinterest-icon.png" alt="pintrest" height="40" width="40"/></a></li>
            </ul>
            </section>
            <section>
                <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/white/book-xxl.png" alt="icon" width="128" height="128"/>
            </section>
    </footer> 
    <footer class= "second">
        <p> @University, School of Information Technology. This web page has been developed as a student assignment for this uni, Introduction to Web Development. Therefore it is not part of the University's authorised web site. DO NOT USE THE INFORMATION CONTAINED ON THIS WEB PAGE IN ANY WAY."</p>
        </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what's in blueberry.css

Comment: can you send the demo for that

Comment: The console logs `TypeError: $(...).blueberry is not a function`... are you sure you are properly referencing the library?

Comment: The problem is you haven't import blueberry.js properly

Comment: The code given is working for me. You have not import your blueberry.js file correctly

Comment: How do i import it correctly??

Comment: how do i do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .blueberry { margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; }
        .blueberry .slides {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .blueberry .slides li {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .blueberry .slides li img {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: none;
        }
        .blueberry .slides li.active { display: block; position: relative; }
        .blueberry .crop li img { width: auto; }

        .blueberry .pager {
            height: 40px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .blueberry .pager li { display: inline-block; }
        .blueberry .pager li a,
        .blueberry .pager li a span {
            display: block;
            height: 4px;
            width: 4px;
        }
        .blueberry .pager li a {
            padding: 18px 8px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
            -moz-border-radius: 6px;
            -o-border-radius: 6px;
            -ms-border-radius: 6px;
            -khtml-border-radius: 6px;
            border-radius: 6px;

        }
        .blueberry .pager li a span {
            overflow: hidden;
            background: #c0c0c0;
            text-indent: -9999px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
            -moz-border-radius: 2px;
            -o-border-radius: 2px;
            -ms-border-radius: 2px;
            -khtml-border-radius: 2px;
            border-radius: 2px;

        }
        .blueberry .pager li.active a span { background: #404040; }
        *{
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body {
            background: #F0F0F0;
            font: 14px/20px Arial, San-Serif;
            color: #555;
            margin: 0;
        }
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 180%;
            line-height: 120%;
            padding: 5% 0:
        }
        h2 {
            text-decoration: underline;
            line-height: 280%;
            padding-left: 2%;
        }
        h3  {
            line-height: 110%;
            padding: 5% 0;
        }
        p {
            padding: 1%;
        }
        a {
            color: #FFF;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        a:hover {
            color: #FFF;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        header {
            background: #405580;
            width: 100%;
            height: 86px;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 100;
            opacity: 0.90;
        }
        #logo {
            maergin: 20px;
            float: left;
            width: 600px;
            height: 79px;
            background: url(http://images.cooltext.com/4390568.png) no-repeat center;
        }
        nav {
            float: right;
            padding: 35px 20px 20px 0;
        }
        #menu-icon {
            display:hidden;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            background: url(http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/icon.png) center;
        }
        a:hover#menu-icon {
            border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
        }
        ul {
            list-style: none
        }
        nav ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            floating: left;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .current {
            color: #FFF;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        #doc {
            margin: 40px 0;
        }
        #content {
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 1140;
            margin-top: 110px;
        }
        .blueberry {
            max-width: 960px;
            margin-top: 110px;
        }
        section {
            width: 29%;
            float: left;
            margin: 2% 1%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }
        article {
            float: left;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 50%;
            height: auto;
            padding: 4%;
        }
        aside {
            float: right;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 35%;
            height: auto;
            padding: 3%;
        }
        ul. gym li {
            padding-left: 3%
        }
        footer {
            background: #333333;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            opacity: 0.90%;
        }
        footer p, footer h3 {
            color: #FFF;
        }
        footer p a {
            color: #FFF;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        ul.social li {
            display: inline;
        }
        ul.social li img {
            height: 50px;
        }
        footer.second {
            border-top: 1px solid #4D4E50;
            background-color: #333333;
            max-height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            opacity: 0.95;
        }
        /*------------------MEDIA!!----------*/
        @media screen and (max-width: 478px) {
            body {
                position: absolute;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 740px) {
            header {
                position: absolute
            }
            #menu-icon {
                display: inline-block
            }nav ul, nav: active ul {
                 display: none;
                 position: absolute;
                 padding: 20px;
                 background: #405580;
                 border: 1px solid #FFF;
                 right: 20px;
                 top: 60px;
                 width: 50%;
                 border-radius: 2px 0 2px 2px;
             }
            nav li {
                text-align: center;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 10px 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
            nav:hover ul {
                display: block;
            }
            section {
                float: left;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            article {
                float: left;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            aside {
                float: left;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        }

        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src= "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marktuk/Blueberry/master/jquery.blueberry.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('.blueberry').blueberry();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <a href="#" id="logo"></a>
    <nav>
        <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class= "current">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Orders</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav><br />
</header>
<div id="doc">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="blueberry">
            <ul class="slides" >
                <li><img src="http://skelbiu-img.dgn.lt/1_5_206818520/surenkame-knygas.jpg" alt="BookOpening" width="960" height="476" /> </li>
                <li><img src="http://www.abc.net.au/news/image/5668412-3x2-940x627.jpg " alt="BookSection" width="960" height="476" /> </li>
                <li><img src="http://s3-ec.buzzfed.com/static/2014-10/22/15/enhanced/webdr10/edit-wide-942-1414005865-6.jpg" alt="BookLane" width="960" height="476" /> </li>
                <li><img src="http://pfauth.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/03_Shakespeare_and_Company-975x327.jpg" alt="BookRange" width="960" height="476" /> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<section>
    <img src="http://www.sunlitemitre10.com.au/site/assets/media/tick.png" alt="Tick" width="70" height="70" />
    <h1> WELCOME! </h1>
    <p> Hello! Welcome to our website. If you are a local... see you in real time and space on your next visit ... for cheap secondhand books. If you're from somewhere else, come talk to us on the World Wide Web, and if you're visiting Geelong anytime soon, we hope you'll come by.</p>
</section>
<section>
    <img src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/Bcg/Krr/BcgKrr9zi.png" alt="Tick" width="70" height="70"  />
    <h1> GOOD NEWS </h1>
    <p> All books are going to be 5% off in July and December, 2015! We'll be selling a range of secondhand books, and selected new ones.</p>
</section>
<section>
    <img src="http://www.sunlitemitre10.com.au/site/assets/media/tick.png" alt="Tick" width="70" height="70" />
    <h1> HISTORY </h1>
    <p> In August 2001, Mary and John have opened this used book shop located in: 123 Moorabool Street, in Geelong.
        Since 2015, we have  started opening at 9 a.m.!  We must be the only book shop in Geelong that open up at this hour, and it's  been said to be the best Secondhand Bookshop in Geelong.</p>
</section>
<div class="clear"></div>
<section>
    <h1> Do you have books to sell? </h1>
    <img src= "http://mycollegeguide.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/selling_books_2.jpg" alt="sell" width="400" height="350" />
    <p> We are always on the look out for secondhand books. Do try us if you have any that you no longer require, we may well be interested, for cash or exchange. PLEASE PHONE FIRST, to arrange a convenient time. </p>
</section>
<section>
    <h2> IMPORTANT NOTICE! </h2>
    <img src="http://storage.googleapis.com/wzukusers/user-14023369/images/559eb2ee1fbecjiSir57/Fanned-Book1cropped_400.jpg" alt="imp" width="400" height="353" />
    <p> From Monday October 5th to Friday October 10th, we will be closing early, for stocktake. The shop will be open until 1pm. Saturday, on the  11th we will return to normal trading hours. Apologies for any inconvenience.</p>
</section>
<section>
    <h1> Take a read </h1>
    <img src="https://writesandwrongsblog.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/elylanguages_1892125c.jpg" alt="sit" width="460" height="288" />
    <p> Come and stop by the reading area and see if we've got the book that you're looking for in stock. We also got stock cards, wrapping paper and various journals and more. </p>
</section>
<footer>
    <section>
        <h3><b> Best Second-hand Bookshop in Geelong </b></h3>
        <p> <b> - Mary & John </b><br><br>
        </p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h3> Connect with Us! </h3>
        <ul class="social" >
            <li> <a href="#"><img src= "http://lifeallieslab.com/images/fb-icon.png" alt="fb" height="59" width="55"/></a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"><img src= "http://pictures.dealer.com/d/dickdyervolvovcna/0008/0304ac7e766dd3685950e8f2fba330a0x.jpg" alt="g" height="36" width="36"/></a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"><img src= "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/twitter_circle_color-512.png" alt="twitter" height="40" width="40"/></a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"><img src= "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/256/pinterest-icon.png" alt="pintrest" height="40" width="40"/></a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section>
        <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/white/book-xxl.png" alt="icon" width="128" height="128"/>
    </section>
</footer>
<footer class= "second">
    <p> @University, School of Information Technology. This web page has been developed as a student assignment for this uni, Introduction to Web Development. Therefore it is not part of the University's authorised web site. DO NOT USE THE INFORMATION CONTAINED ON THIS WEB PAGE IN ANY WAY."</p>
</footer>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>Blueberry - A simple, fluid, responsive jQuery image slider.</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="blueberry.css" />

    <style type="text/css">
            *{
                margin: 0;
                border: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            body {
                background: #F0F0F0;
                font: 14px/20px Arial, San-Serif;
                color: #555;    
                margin: 0;
            }
            h1 { 
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 180%;
                line-height: 120%;
                padding: 5% 0:
            }
            h2 {
                text-decoration: underline;
                line-height: 280%;
                padding-left: 2%;   
            }
            h3  {
                line-height: 110%;
                padding: 5% 0;
            }
            p {
                padding: 1%;    
            }
            a {
                color: #FFF;    
                text-decoration: none;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            a:hover {
                color: #FFF;
                text-decoration: underline; 
            }
            header {
                background: #405580;
                width: 100%;
                height: 86px;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                z-index: 100;
                opacity: 0.90;  
            }
            #logo {
                maergin: 20px;
                float: left;
                width: 600px;
                height: 79px;
                background: url(http://images.cooltext.com/4390568.png) no-repeat center;
            }
            nav {
                float: right;
                padding: 35px 20px 20px 0;
            }
            #menu-icon {
                display:hidden;
                width: 40px;
                height: 40px;
                background: url(http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/icon.png) center;
            }
            a:hover#menu-icon {
                border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
            }
            ul {
                list-style: none    
            }
            nav ul li {
                display: inline-block;
                floating: left;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            .current {
                color: #FFF;
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
            #doc {
                margin: 40px 0;
            }
            #content {
                margin: 0 auto;
                max-width: 1140;
                margin-top: 110px;
            }
            .blueberry {
                max-width: 960px;
                margin-top: 110px;  
            }
            section {
                width: 29%;
                float: left;
                margin: 2% 2%;
                text-align: center; 
            }
            .clear {
                clear: both;
            }
            article {
                float: left;
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 50%;
                height: auto;
                padding: 4%;
            }
            aside {
                float: right;
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 35%;
                height: auto;
                padding: 3%;
            }
            ul. gym li {
                padding-left: 3%
            }
            footer {
                background: #333333;
                width: 100%;    
                overflow: hidden;
                opacity: 0.90%;
            }
            footer p, footer h3 {
                color: #FFF;
            }
            footer p a {
                color: #FFF;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            ul.social li {
                display: inline;
            }
            ul.social li img {
                height: 50px;
            }
            footer.second {
                border-top: 1px solid #4D4E50;
                background-color: #333333;
                max-height: 50px;
                text-align: center;
                opacity: 0.95;
            } 
            /*------------------MEDIA!!----------*/
            @media screen and (max-width: 478px) {
                body { 
                    position: absolute;
                }
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 740px) {
                header {
                    position: absolute 
                }
                #menu-icon {
                    display: inline-block
                }nav ul, nav: active ul {
                    display: none;
                    position: absolute;
                    padding: 20px;
                    background: #405580;
                    border: 1px solid #FFF;
                    right: 20px;
                    top: 60px;
                    width: 50%;
                    border-radius: 2px 0 2px 2px;
                }
                nav li {
                    text-align: center;
                    width: 100%;
                    padding: 10px 0;
                    margin: 0;
                }
                nav:hover ul {
                    display: block;
                }
                section { 
                    float: left;
                    width: 100%;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                }
                article { 
                    float: left;
                    width: 100%;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                }
                aside { 
                    float: left;
                    width: 100%;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                }
            }

            }
            </style>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="jquery.blueberry.js"></script>

            <script>
            $(window).load(function() {
                $('.blueberry').blueberry();
            });
            </script>

            </head>
            <body>

            <header>
                    <a href="#" id="logo"></a>
                    <nav>
                        <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" class= "current">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Orders</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </nav><br />
            </header>

            <div id="doc">
              <div id="content">

            <!-- blueberry -->

                <div class="blueberry">
                  <ul class="slides">
                     <li><img src="http://skelbiu-img.dgn.lt/1_5_206818520/surenkame-knygas.jpg" alt="BookOpening" width="960" height="476" /> </li>
                                <li><img src="http://www.abc.net.au/news/image/5668412-3x2-940x627.jpg " alt="BookSection" width="960" height="476" /> </li>
                              <li><img src="http://s3-ec.buzzfed.com/static/2014-10/22/15/enhanced/webdr10/edit-wide-942-1414005865-6.jpg" alt="BookLane" width="960" height="476" /> </li>
                              <li><img src="http://pfauth.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/03_Shakespeare_and_Company-975x327.jpg" alt="BookRange" width="960" height="476" /> </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>

            <!-- blueberry -->

              </div>
            </div>
            <section>            
                 <img src="http://www.sunlitemitre10.com.au/site/assets/media/tick.png" alt="Tick" width="70" height="70" />
                   <h1> WELCOME! </h1>
                    <p> Hello! Welcome to our website. If you are a local... see you in real time and space on your next visit ... for cheap secondhand books. If you're from somewhere else, come talk to us on the World Wide Web, and if you're visiting Geelong anytime soon, we hope you'll come by.</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                 <img src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/Bcg/Krr/BcgKrr9zi.png" alt="Tick" width="70" height="70"  />
                   <h1> GOOD NEWS </h1>
                    <p> All books are going to be 5% off in July and December, 2015! We'll be selling a range of secondhand books, and selected new ones.</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                   <img src="http://www.sunlitemitre10.com.au/site/assets/media/tick.png" alt="Tick" width="70" height="70" />
                    <h1> HISTORY </h1>
                    <p> In August 2001, Mary and John have opened this used book shop located in: 123 Moorabool Street, in Geelong. 
            Since 2015, we have  started opening at 9 a.m.!  We must be the only book shop in Geelong that open up at this hour, and it's  been said to be the best Secondhand Bookshop in Geelong.</p>
                </section>
              <div class="clear"></div>  
                 <section>
                    <h1> Do you have books to sell? </h1>
                    <img src= "http://mycollegeguide.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/selling_books_2.jpg" alt="sell" width="400" height="350" /> 
                    <p> We are always on the look out for secondhand books. Do try us if you have any that you no longer require, we may well be interested, for cash or exchange. PLEASE PHONE FIRST, to arrange a convenient time. </p>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <h2> IMPORTANT NOTICE! </h2>
                   <img src="http://storage.googleapis.com/wzukusers/user-14023369/images/559eb2ee1fbecjiSir57/Fanned-Book1cropped_400.jpg" alt="imp" width="400" height="353" />
            <p> From Monday October 5th to Friday October 10th, we will be closing early, for stocktake. The shop will be open until 1pm. Saturday, on the  11th we will return to normal trading hours. Apologies for any inconvenience.</p>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <h1> Take a read </h1>
                    <img src="https://writesandwrongsblog.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/elylanguages_1892125c.jpg" alt="sit" width="460" height="288" />
                    <p> Come and stop by the reading area and see if we've got the book that you're looking for in stock. We also got stock cards, wrapping paper and various journals and more. </p>
                    </section>
                 <footer>
                    <section>
                        <h3><b> Best Second-hand Bookshop in Geelong </b></h3>
                        <p> <b> - Mary & John </b><br><br>
                         </p>
                    </section>

                    <section>
                        <h3> Connect with Us! </h3>
                        <ul class="social" >
                            <li> <a href="#"><img src= "http://lifeallieslab.com/images/fb-icon.png" alt="fb" height="59" width="55"/></a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#"><img src= "http://pictures.dealer.com/d/dickdyervolvovcna/0008/0304ac7e766dd3685950e8f2fba330a0x.jpg" alt="g" height="36" width="36"/></a></li> 
                            <li> <a href="#"><img src= "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/twitter_circle_color-512.png" alt="twitter" height="40" width="40"/></a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#"><img src= "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/256/pinterest-icon.png" alt="pintrest" height="40" width="40"/></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </section>
                        <section>
                            <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/white/book-xxl.png" alt="icon" width="128" height="128"/>
                        </section>
                </footer> 
                <footer class= "second">
                    <p> @University, School of Information Technology. This web page has been developed as a student assignment for this uni, Introduction to Web Development. Therefore it is not part of the University's authorised web site. DO NOT USE THE INFORMATION CONTAINED ON THIS WEB PAGE IN ANY WAY."</p>
                    </footer></body>
            </html>
```